# Sequence of polynomials converging to zero function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, approximation-theory

Find a sequence of polynomials $(f_n)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ point wise on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f_n(x) \rightarrow 3$. Calculate $\int_0^1 \sup_n |f_n(x)| dx$ for this sequence of polynomials.

Any help with this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't want pointwise convergence on (0,1) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f_n(x)= c_nx^n(1-x)$, we have

$$
\int_0^1f_n(x)=c_n\int_0^1x^n(1-x)\mathrm dx=\frac{c_n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^{n+1}\mathrm dx=\frac{c_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}\;,
$$

so for $c_n=3(n+1)(n+2)$ the integral comes out right, and $3(n+1)(n+2)x^n(1-x)\to0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, so the pointwise limit is $0$ on all of $[0,1]$ (including the endpoints).

P.S.: I just realized I forgot about the second part of the question; calculating that integral would be rather difficult for this sequence, and I don't immediately see how one might find a sequence for which it wouldn't be.

Comment: I did come up with the same function. But I thought there would be a nicer form of the function so that I can do part 2. Thanks anyway. Do let me know if you come across something.

Comment: @pondy: That's a very good example of why it's a good idea to include your own attempts in the question. Not only does it give people the impression that you've made an effort yourself before turning to others for assistance, it also avoids the inefficiency of people telling you what you already know.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Without proof: you can probably show that $f_{n+1}(x)>f_n(x)$ for $x>(n+1)/(n+3)$ and $f_{n+1}(x)<f_n(x)$ and $x<(n+1)/(n+3)$. That means for the sup you have to integrate $f_0$ from $0$ to $2/4$, $f_1$ from $2/4$ to $3/5$ and so on and sum that up. (I checked that using Sage up to $n=10$, but don't have time to prove that currently)

Comment: Again without proof: You can find that $\sup|f_n(x)|$ is monotone increasing. Using that you can find a lower bound for the integral as $\sup|f_n(x)|\geq \sum_n f_n(x_n)(x_{n+1}-x_n) = 12 \frac{(n+1) n^n}{(n+2)^{n+1} (n+3)}$ with $x_n=n/(n+2)$. As you can see, the summand grows like $O(1/n)$ and the sum will diverge. And the same will do the integral.

Comment: @joriki I was wondering if I can come up with a continuous function and use Weierstrass, so that I can find sup easily. I wanted to know if I am thinking on the right lines

Comment: @pondy: I'm not sure what you mean -- polynomials are continuous functions. You mean a non-polynomial continuous function? I don't see why obtaining the polynomials by approximating non-polynomial functions should make it easier to find the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

How about $f_n=c_nx^{a_n-1}(1-x)^{b_n-1}$,for some increasing positive integer sequences $\{a_n\}$,$\{b_n\}$,which satisfies $3\Gamma(a_n+b_n)=c_n\Gamma(a_n)\Gamma(b_n)$ ?

Comment: These polynomials are everywhere $\le1$, so their integral is always $\le1$ and doesn't tend to $3$.